# How to configure aspectj to get post-compile weaving (with maven)?

Tags: maven, configuration, pom.xml, aspectj, compile-time-weaving

How to configure AspectJ in order to get post-compile weaving? I just replaced "compile" with "post-compile" in the plugin below: (needless to say that was unseccessful)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>post-compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**but I miss something as it gives the following error:**

```
'post-compile' was specified in an execution, but not found in the plugin
```

Comment: Your post mentions post-compile weaving but is tagged "load-time-weaving". These are two distinct things - from docs, ["the weaving process itself can take place at one of three different times: compile-time, post-compile time, and load-time."](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw.html). Which are you after?

Answer (score 7):

The JAR files containing the classes to weave must be listed as `<dependencies/>` in the Maven project and listed as `<weaveDependencies/>` in the `<configuration>` of the aspectj-maven-plugin. From http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/weaveJars.html:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.13</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.agroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>to-weave</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.anothergroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>gen</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
        <configuration>
          <weaveDependencies>
            <weaveDependency>
              <groupId>org.agroup</groupId>
              <artifactId>to-weave</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>
            <weaveDependency>
              <groupId>org.anothergroup</groupId>
              <artifactId>gen</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>
          </weaveDependencies>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  <build>
  ...
</project>
```