# Spring aop intercept MongoTemplate

Tags: spring, mongodb, aspectj, spring-data-mongodb, spring-aop

The MongoTemplate class has a nested class -QueryCursorPreparer. My task is to intercept the QueryCursorPreparer.getReadPreference () method. How could I do this? When trying to do this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MongoInterceptor {

  @Around("execution(* org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.*(..))")
  public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("TEST");
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

Nothing is intercepted

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: My task is simple, I want to manage ReadPreference not from the repository level. For example, I want anatation to RestController to control what is in this thread of execution, reading will be done through Secondary members. To do this, I want to write an interceptor on MongoTemplate that would intercept the getReadPreference method and substitute the value I need there, depending on the presence of annotations in this process.

Comment: @Dima, glancing at the [`MongoTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) Javadoc it looks as if that class is not a Spring bean/component. This would explain why you cannot target it with a Spring AOP aspect. Unless you find another means to achieve your goal, you can still switch to Spring-controlled native AspectJ and get rid of that limitation. Then your aspect would work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the post-compile weaving? Since you are trying to advice a 3rd party code (you don't own the source code). Maybe these could help :

- [Unable to enable post-compile weave mode in IntelliJ for a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65119382/unable-to-enable-post-compile-weave-mode-in-intellij-for-a-module)
- [How to configure aspectj to get post-compile weaving (with maven)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679502/how-to-configure-aspectj-to-get-post-compile-weaving-with-maven)